# sometimes when adding new fields in index, they don't get indexed in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nosql

Let's say I have an index `test` and which already exists. I want to add a new field `newfield1` with some data for all documents in the database. Currently I am simply deleting all everything and then reinserting the data with the `newfield1` data added in. I understand this isn't the most efficient way, but that's not my question right now.

Sometimes the data in `newfield1` does not get indexed and I can't visualize it in Kibana. It's pretty annoying. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

NOTE: I CAN query this field in ElasticSearch which makes me think there's a problem with Kibana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kibana caches the field mapping.   Go to Settings -> Indices, select your index, and click the orange "Refresh" button.

Comment: Everybody hits it; that's how I knew :)

Comment: I can't believe how often this happens and how simple the solution is :)

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here but first make sure your cluster is Green.

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

If you are still struggling to understand the state of you cluster then perhaps consider installing on of the plugins like HQ https://github.com/royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ